# Blunder while looking for a short circuit on a motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard

After getting my laptop diagnosed with a shorted motherboard, I decided to see if I could find the short and fix it or replace the motherboard itself.

I blew compressed air to ice over some components, then plugged it into the AC adapter. That might've been an enormous error, as a corner of the circuit board started to smoke.

Was that because of the short or because a bare motherboard shouldn't be plugged into an adapter?

Comment: What’s your question? How you killed the motherboard? I think the bare motherboard is not the issue. Almost impossible to say exactly _what_ is the cause of the burnout, but it was definitely not related to powering up a bare motherboard.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, yeah, that was my question.

Comment: Your troubleshooting procedure makes no sense. A "*short*" is not alleviated nor tested by cooling the circuit. For that matter, where did the diagnosis of "*a shorted motherboard*" come from? What were the symptoms that indicated a "*short circuit*" rather than an *open* circuit or failed component?

Comment: @sawdust Ah, I just gave it to a laptop repair shop, and they wrote to me saying there was a short circuit somewhere. The price for them to fix was the same as replacing a motherboard, so I decided to try fixing it myself. Here is the video I used as a reference for finding the faulty component: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOALg_rDIZk .

Comment: Even if you had no introduced moister into the mix, the fact there was a short, would have been enough to cause “magic smoke”.  You would have had to trace the short, using a thermal camera (among other tools) to identify, where the short was exactly. Whatever method you used wasn’t effective nor would it have been. Blowing compressed air isn’t effective by itself

Comment: "*A short circuit somewhere*" sounds like a "diagnosis" from someone who really isn't qualified. BTW I've noticed that "*short*" is sometimes carelessly used to refer to any sort of electrical failure. The shorts I've seen typically caused something else to act as a fuse (and burn up). The reason for the same price is because mobo replacement is going to be the repair. The last time I identified a failed component, the chip cost only about 10 cents in Europe & Asia, but was unobtainable in the USA. So identifying the failed part is only half the job, and the repair may not be completable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not wait for the board to dry, and water (moisture) on the board will cause short circuits between any bare conductors, especially if you had the board powered somehow.

My guess is now the motherboard is not readily repairable, but go to a computer repair shop if anything can be done.  I doubt it, though.